# Command LinkStoryboards failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm asking new question because none of the old answers solved my problem. I didn't have any error until i add some ads with cocoapods yesterday. Now i get that error but I didn't change anything in the project.

> /* com.apple.ibtool.warnings */
> : warning: “StringsFiles.plist” couldn’t be removed.
> Underlying Errors:
> Description: The operation couldn’t be completed. Not a directory
> Failure Reason: Not a directory
> /* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
> : error: The file “StringsFiles.plist” couldn’t be opened.
> Underlying Errors:
> Description: The operation couldn’t be completed. Not a directory
> Failure Reason: Not a directory
> Command LinkStoryboards failed with a nonzero exit code

Answer (score 1):

If your **"LinkStoryboards failed with a nonzero exit code"** error was invoked utilizing a Storyboard Reference, I recommend the following:

• Make sure that your target storyboard ViewController has a Storyboard ID in the Identity section of the Identity Inspector.

• In the Attributes Inspector of the Storyboard Reference, double-check the Reference ID (e.g. goHereVC).

• Add a performSegue function in the originating (sender) ViewController file to ensure the target segue identifier is precise.

Encountered and resolved this issue in **Xcode version 12.1(12A7403)/OS Catalina**.